# Jinja throughs "SyntaxError: expected property name, got '%' " error

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js, jinja2

I am using the Flask framework with render_template. Flask return list to the whether.html file. I use Chart.js in the whether.html file to create graphs from the lists returned by the flask. When I use the **Chart.js** code inside the HTML file it works fine but when I want to copy the same javascript code to an external **line.js** file and link it back to my **whether.html** then I see **SyntaxError: expected property name, got '%'**  javascript error in the console.

I would appreciate any help regarding the problem.

**JavaScript within whether.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
<!-- bar chart canvas element -->
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<p id="pointSelected">Point selected:</p>

<script>
  // Global parameters:
  // do not resize the chart canvas when its container does (keep at 600x400px)
  Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

  // define the chart data
  var chartData = {
    labels : [{% for item in labels %}
               "{{item}}",
              {% endfor %}],
    datasets : [{
        label: '{{ legend }}',
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data : [{% for item in values %}
                  {{item}},
                {% endfor %}],
        spanGaps: false
    },

    {
        label: 'Sensor 2',
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        data : [{% for item in values %}
                  {{item + 3}},
                {% endfor %}],

    }
    ]
  }

  // get chart canvas
  var holder = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

  // create the chart using the chart canvas
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                   return tooltipItems.yLabel + ' degrees';
                 }
        }
      },
    }
  });

  // get the text element below the chart
  var pointSelected = document.getElementById("pointSelected");

  // create a callback function for updating the selected index on the chart
  holder.onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    console.log(activePoint);
    console.log('x:' + activePoint[0]._view.x);
    console.log('maxWidth: ' + activePoint[0]._xScale.maxWidth);
    console.log('y: ' + activePoint[0]._view.y);
    console.log('index: ' + activePoint[0]._index);
    pointSelected.innerHTML = 'Point selected... index: ' + activePoint[0]._index;
  };
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

**line.js file**

```
  // Global parameters:
  // do not resize the chart canvas when its container does (keep at 600x400px)
  Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

  // define the chart data
  var chartData = {
    labels : [{% for item in labels %}
               "{{item}}",
              {% endfor %}],
    datasets : [{
        label: '{{ legend }}',
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data : [{% for item in values %}
                  {{item}},
                {% endfor %}],
        spanGaps: false
    },

    {
        label: 'Sensor 2',
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        data : [{% for item in values %}
                  {{item + 3}},
                {% endfor %}],

    }
    ]
  }

  // get chart canvas
  var holder = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

  // create the chart using the chart canvas
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                   return tooltipItems.yLabel + ' degrees';
                 }
        }
      },
    }
  });

  // get the text element below the chart
  var pointSelected = document.getElementById("pointSelected");

  // create a callback function for updating the selected index on the chart
  holder.onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    console.log(activePoint);
    console.log('x:' + activePoint[0]._view.x);
    console.log('maxWidth: ' + activePoint[0]._xScale.maxWidth);
    console.log('y: ' + activePoint[0]._view.y);
    console.log('index: ' + activePoint[0]._index);
    pointSelected.innerHTML = 'Point selected... index: ' + activePoint[0]._index;
  };
```

**whether.html file**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!-- <script src='static/Chart.min.js'></script> -->
<script src='static/js/Chart.js'></script>
<script src='static/js/line.js'></script>
<!-- <canvas id="line-chart" width="300" height="150"></canvas> -->

<h1>Temperature Sensor #1</h1>
    <!-- bar chart canvas element -->
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <p id="pointSelected">Point selected:</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja work only with html files, you can't use it's tags in another files. But you can simply render little script with variables which contains needed values in html template and than use them in external script, for example:

```
    {% extends "index.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <!-- bar chart canvas element -->
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <p id="pointSelected">Point selected:</p>

    <script>
        var labels = [{% for item in labels %}
           "{{item}}",
          {% endfor %}]
        var data = [{% for item in values %}
              {{item}},
            {% endfor %}]
        // and so on for each variable
        // it's important to import external script 
        // after variables declaration, not before
    </script>

    <script src="external-script.js"></script>

    {% endblock %}
```

and than you can simply use them in external script like:

```
    var chartData = {
        labels : labels,
        // and so on
    };
```

Comment: One correction: Jinja2 will happily work on anything in `templates/` that you pass through `render_template()`, including `.js` files. You just need to be very careful about escaping things correctly for JavaScript.